# How do I keep a table-reference static when the columns change order

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm referencing a table, as below, where the headings have specific names that I want to summarize.

```
=SUMIF(Table[Heading1];Sheet1!$A2;Table[Heading2])
```

The challenge is that input data for the table can change, adding new columns and changing orders of the columns. The headings names will remain the same.

For some reason Excel changes the reference within the formula to match the heading of the "new" column that is in the position of the old one.

**Example**: if a new column is introduced between [Header1] and [Header2] the formula above will be changed to and the reference to [Header2] will be changed to the header of the new column, here [Header3]:

```
=SUMIF(Table[Header1];Sheet1!$A2;Table[Header3])
```

I would very much like to keep the formula intact always referencing the headers I have specified. How to I accomplish this, and stopping Excel from changing the references?

Answer (score 0):

You need to double up the table references with a colon between them. So:

`Table[Heading1]` will become `Table[[Heading1]:[Heading1]]`